# How can I style a Select from Material UI with styled components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm trying

```
export const StyledAppSelect = styled(Select)`
  &:before {
    border-color: white;
  }

  &:after {
    border-color: white;
  }
  color: white;
`
```

But that doesn't seem to change the font color or the border color. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to know how to style it - you first need to check what HTML is actually generated for that component. Because some styles you can apply to the top level `<div>` and some styles you might need to apply to nested elements.

Here is an example:

```
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

// width or color can be set on top level
// but to get styled border you need to style nested div
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  width: 100px;
  color: red;
  & > div {
    border: 2px solid green;
  }
`;
....
....
// somewhere in where you need to render it
<StyledSelect>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</StyledSelect>
```

And here is how it can look like (but I haven't changed icon or `:hover` etc. That is why what you can see on the picture is a bit weird):

[image]

To style icon you can add this:

```
& > svg {
    color: red;
}
```

Or you can change input's bottom border:

```
// yeah, sometimes it's not that easy to override frameworks styles :)
// so, to figure out what to override you need to check what framework generates for you
// e.g. this ":hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before" is how Material adds
// bottom border when you hover input (the dark line on the img I attached above), so that's the way how we can override it
&:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

Hope you get the idea :)

Comment: When it's `active`, it doesn't keep the color

Comment: And what about the icon?

Comment: @Shamoon I've updated my answer with stuff for icon, and I hope you get the idea. Check in your browser what HTML is generated by Select component - and then you can style it. CSS pseudo classes (`:hover` etc.) are also supported.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

```
export const StyledAppSelect = styled.(Select)`
  & .MuiOutlinedInput-input {
    border-color: white;
  }

  & .MuiInputBase-formControl {
    border-color: white;
  }
`
```

If you inspect elements you will see class names for material ui elements, I just left example now

Comment: I don't want to use the default select. I want to use a material select

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass attribute style as below and use class names documented in [api](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) section:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";


const StyledSelect = styled(Select).attrs({
  classes: { root: "root" }
})`
  .root {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <StyledSelect
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={10}
        onChange={() => {}}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </StyledSelect>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override the select classes from a css, I for example use styled-components. You can find the classes to override in the following link: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/

According to this page Select has available a prop called **input**, to which you can pass an element. This means that you can pass styled input to it.

If we now go to the input(https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/) documentation we see the classes we have to override, like: .MuiInputBase-input, label...So if we style the input and pass it to the select... Magic, we have that part styled.

**Input styles:**

```
const SelectInputStyles = styled(InputBase)`
${({ theme }) => css`
    label {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
    .MuiInputBase-input {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: ${theme.colors.mainColor};
        border: solid 1px ${theme.colors.mainColor};
        padding: 1rem 2.6rem 1rem 1.2rem;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    &:focus {
        box-shadow: ' 0px 0px 2px 1px  #00ffab';
    }
`}`;
```

**SelectStyles** (You can use Select directly, but I was also changing the color of the icon. These styles are for the icon color only.):

```
const SelectStyles = styled(Select)`
${({ theme }) => css`
    .MuiSelect-icon {
        color: ${theme.colors.mainColor};
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
`}`;
```

**Select:**

```
 <SelectStyles
        input={<SelectInputStyles />}
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={valueSelected}
        label={labelText}
        onChange={onChangeDropdown}>
        {options.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem value={option.value} key={option.value}>
                {option.text}
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
    </SelectStyles>
```

**Result:**

[image]